# What is the minimum time difference between 2 questions?

Tags: support, asking-questions, rate-limiting

> What is the minimum time difference between 2 questions ?

Like I have recently posted a geometry question but I also got a FE doubt and I want to ask it as soon as possible, but if I post it immediately, people might think that I haven't tried it for sufficient time which is not true. So is there any minimum time difference which should be there between 2 questions?

PS: It has been only 2 months since I joined MSE, so please excuse me if it sounds too obvious.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The limit is [40 minutes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/322265/4751173), but it only applies if you have less than 125 reputation. There is no limit for users like you, who are supposed to know that you shouldn't flood the site with too many questions at once. IMHO, two (well-written) questions in short succession shouldn't be a real problem; people probably won't even notice it. Do include your research so far, not because people might think you didn't try hard enough, but because it will help in giving answers that are better suited to your level of understanding.