# "You can only post once every 40 minutes."

Tags: support, reputation, asking-questions, new-users, rate-limiting

Dear all friendly mathematicians,

When I tried to post my question on this site - I saw

> "You can only post once every 40 minutes."

Is there a restriction on that in general? Or is that due to my low reputation? How much reputation do I need to gain to avoid such an issue?

Do I need to get that threshold reputation on each of the stackexchange site to avoid this issue on each site?

Many thanks!

M

Comment: Since I see that you have already asked 11 questions in August, I will add a reminder that you can ask [at most 50 question per month](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4742/should-we-ask-for-question-quotas-like-those-that-have-been-available-for-the-bi/4770#4770). (This information is mentioned also in the FAQ post linked in quid's answer.)

Comment: Does that limit depend on the reputation? thanks

Comment: The limit to 6 question per day and 50 question per month (including deleted questions) is for all users, regardless of the reputation.

Comment: I will add links to some related posts on this meta: [What is the minimum time difference between 2 questions?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/32509) and [Is there a limit on number of questions a user can ask in a given time frame?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29694)

Comment: I also see "You can only ask 6 questions in a 24-hour period." is this due to the reputation threshold below which value? thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The threshold is 125 points. You are exempt on the site where you have that many points not all sites.

To note, all questions asked in the network count. Actually it is even IP based.

See [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide) for further details.

Comment: thanks let me read this rule carefully ")

Comment: "You are exempt on the site where you have that many points not all sites." -> can you clarify - I cannot understand this

Comment: It is meant to answer the question "Do I need to get that threshold reputation on each of the stackexchange site to avoid this issue on each site?" The answer is "yes"

Comment: thanks - that is all clear!

Comment: I also see "You can only ask 6 questions in a 24-hour period." is this due to the reputation threshold below which value? thanks!

Comment: That is a restriction that does not depend on reputation points.

Comment: thanks - does that restriction apply to 6 questions per stack exchange site? or the sum 6 for all questions on all sites?

Comment: It's per site, and only in place on a few sites. [SO], [SU], [SF], our site.