# Why sometimes when I post a problem I need to wait for 40 minutes?

Tags: support, asking-questions, rate-limiting

I recently was trying to post a maths problem but when I click on submit it tells me that you can post once in every 40minutes as such I didn't post anything at all before this in few months so why this is showing up?  Is this a bug or something please help? (Same happened when I was asking this in meta too right now one, there also it says to wait for 40 minutes so what you all are seeing is the meta post which I typed 40min ago) and now I need to wait for 40 more min to post the math problem because I posted in meta so don't know why it counted it as one time.

Comment: Sorry for prior message, made a mistake. But it seems you have posted the question now. You may want to see the asking section in https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide

Comment: Sir i have nothing posted before in 40 min and stuff , i just mean to say if i try to ask a new question after 24 hours then also it will tell me to wait for 40 min etc...my prior this month activity is very very less

Comment: Looking at the "[The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899)", it seems the the 40 minutes limit is IP-based. (And it only applies to the users below 125 reputation points.)

Comment: I see understood now Sir thanks for help

Comment: Minor note:  the use of "sir" here is potentially offensive, as there are many folk on this site who do not identify as male.  Also, in most of the western world, the terms "sir" and "ma'am" are considered overly formal and awkward.  I would suggest that you attempt to remove these words from your English vocabulary.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I won’t disagree but let me just say 1 as the person addressed I was not offended and 2 I was taught to use sir in my commonwealth country primary school English class!

Comment: @CalvinKhor I was not speaking up specifically on your behalf.  Rather, the use of "sir" when addressing people on Math SE is something which I observe quite frequently, and it is often directed towards people who do not identify as "sir".  It is best, in general, to leave such pleasantries aside.

Comment: @GEdgar  Don't doxx me.... :) :)

Comment: @GEdgar That's a bit of a slippery slope. Not only is the usage of sir common throughout most commonwealth regions, not just Singapore, but it reinforces a Western-centric view on what English is considered appropriate. That bothers me a lot.

Comment: @RushabhMehta, I get the feeling you meant to reply to Xander?

Comment: @CalvinKhor No, I'm okay with Xander's point, as long as consideration is taken to understand why sir is so commonly used (it isn't meant to be disrespectful). GEdgar's comment, on the other hand, insinuates that sir shouldn't be used here **because** it is a feature of Singaporean English, which I find to be inappropriate.

Comment: @Rushabh:   Do you address a women professor as "sir"?  I've never heard that valid in any culture.

Comment: @GEdgar ^^^ Same question for you?  It is not only boys and men that pursue mathematics, to teach and research.  So do not assume the gender of whom you speak with.

Comment: @amWhy I don't. Xander mentioned sir and madam/ma'am, which is the point of discussion. I only mentioned sir as that was all that was mentioned in GEdgar's remark. I think you are jumping to conclusions.

Comment: On the internet, you don't know if one is a dog, or a man, or boy, or woman, or girl or a robot.  Don't make assumptions.  That's all Xander was suggesting.  I'm assuming you'd rather not have me to refer to a man, and "Ma'am", when I really don't know you are?

Comment: @amWhy I suggest reading the chain of discussion more carefully. I agreed with Xander's point, with the caveat of being considerate to those who have grown up in different environments. I took offense to another comment in this thread, which prompted my response.

Comment: My highschool English Teacher referred to everyone in my English class, as "gentlepeople", singularly, "gentleperson".  There are ways to be respectful on the internet, with out assuming an anonymous user is a "sir".  That's all I'm saying.

Comment: @amWhy I'm aware of your point. I didn't appreciate your assumption that I was somehow for misgendering users. A bit of consideration for those who grew up in different backgrounds is not a tough ask.

Comment: Applying a blanket address of "Sir" on this site will cerntainly lead to misgendering.  And I would ask that: Sensitivity to the damage and insult to others, when you call all anonymous folks in math, a "Sir" (when they are not), and consideration for women who have historically, until very recently been shut out of math, is not much to ask.

Comment: @RushabhMehta the way I read it, GEdgar said "Do X when in Y", but you have interpreted it as "Do X only when in Y" i.e. the reverse implication. At the same time, when in Germany, speaking german makes communication smoother. The same is true to a lesser extent for a website that usually "speaks in western english", which is why I do not use sir/madam here. And for others on the receiving end of the “Sirs”, I hope the above discussion help people understand that the Sirs are fundamentally based on the principle to Be Nice!

Comment: The reason why I pointed out that Xander was not speaking out for me was to avoid people assuming generalities by contextualising the situation. I do not know what I can say in general, other than that I try to treat people with the dignity I expect from them in return, and I do not wish harm even to people I disagree with. In the present case, given that if not for our names, many social and sensory cues are absent online, it was not a large leap to assume that I (and Martin) would not object to Sir. And given *that*, IMO there was no need for GEdgar to change the language already in use.

Comment: @CalvinKhor That is a good point.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The 40-minute-limit is actually IP-based. So if you share you IP with other users, that would be a possible explanation why you sometimes can't post a new question and have to wait.

---

I will quote from the [current revision](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/164900/136) of the [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899#164900) (from the section on Asking):

> Users with < 125 rep on the current site, [40 minutes since their last question anywhere on the network](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/322265) (This applies to the user's IP address, *not* their account. If the user shares that IP with other users, they can be limited by the other user asking a question anywhere on the network; similarly, if the same user posts a question from a different IP address, [they may not be limited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/341711).)

---

Some related posts on this site:

- ["You can only post once every 40 minutes."](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33978)
- [Is there a limit on number of questions a user can ask in a given time frame?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29694)
- [What is the minimum time difference between 2 questions?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/32509)